# Type mismatch: inferred type is ViewPagerAdapterS but PagerAdapter? was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

i am trying to implement viewpager and tablyout in android studio using kotlin
i have tried fragmentpageradapter but it is not longer used

this is the adapter

```
package com.example.pgm

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter


 class ViewPagerAdapterS(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        var fragment: Fragment? = null
        when(position)
        {
            0 -> {fragment = VSFragment()}
            1 -> {fragment = IVSFragment()}

        }

        return fragment!!
    }

    fun getPAgeTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        var title: String? = null
        when(position)
        {
            0 -> {title = "Active Subscription"}
            1 -> {title = "Inactive Subscription"}

        }

        return title!!
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

     override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
         TODO("Not yet implemented")
     }


 }
```

```
    and this is the activity
```

```
package com.example.pgm

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

class ViewSubscriptionsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_subscriptions)
        val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewpagers)
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapterS(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

and this is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ViewSubscriptionsActivity"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpagers"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabss"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i get the error
Type mismatch: inferred type is ViewPagerAdapterS but PagerAdapter? was expected

So, what can i do?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the classes of Viewpager (1) and Viewpager2 these are two totally independent implementations of a View pager.

You don't show your xml of `activity_view_subscriptions`

but the import `import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`
is for the [original Viewpager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager)

Your adaptor `import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter`
is from Viewpager2

Change your xml to use `Viewpager2` [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) so that your `val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewpagers)` is the of the right type.